# A right angle relates to orthocenter and circumcenter

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving

I'm struggling to solve this. It would be very nice if you use no knowledge on circle to solve this (this problem was introduced before the context of circle).

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle, with orthocenter $H$, circumcenter $O$. The line parallel to BC passing through $O$ intersects AC at K. Let $I$ be the midpoint of $AH$. Prove that $\widehat{BIK}=90^o$.

[image]

My attempts:
I drew three altitudes, and called them $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ respectively. Let $J$ be the intersection of $EF$ and $AH$. Then I can see that $CJ$ is perpendicular to $BI$ and I'm trying to prove that $CJ$ and $IK$ are parallel.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've got roughly no idea. I draw three altitudes, call AD, BE, CF respectively, let J be the intersection of EF and AH. Then I can see that CJ is perpendicular to BI and I'm trying to prove that CJ and IK are parallel.

Comment: It is very unusual to ask for solving a problem like this without using the knowledge of circles, especially when you have tagged it as a problem in "geometry" and "Euclidean-geometry".

Comment: @Mick Yes I see, but this problem is restricted to use the knowledge up to the similarity of triangles only. Sometimes, the restrictions also help us to be more creative, I think

Comment: Interesting. I would like to see how this problem can be solved via similar triangles only.

Comment: @anonimo: *"this problem is restricted to use the knowledge up to the similarity of triangles only. *" ... Please include such information in the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) This will help people like Reza avoid spending their valuable time and effort composing and formatting a comprehensive answer that you won't accept. ... You might also want to include additional context about these restrictions: Is the problem presented before circle-related results have been taught? Is the problem designed as a challenge to avoid circle-related theorems? etc

Comment: You can use similarities or Thales theorem to show that $AI$ is congruent to the distance between $O$ and side $BC$. This looks promising.

Comment: This is a wonderful configuration. Where did you find it?

Comment: @TheBestMagician I don't remember where I copy this, but it is a problem in my notebook in the section of similarity of triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Let's place your problem on the coordinate system. We may assume that:
$$A=(a,b), \\ B=(-1,0), \\ C=(1,0).$$
Therefore, the equation of $AC$ is $y=\frac{b}{a-1}(x-1).$ And, $O$ is the intersection of $x=0$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ whose equation is $y-\frac{b}{2}=(\frac{1-a}{b})(x-(\frac{a+1}{2})).$ Thus,

$$O=(0, \frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2b}).$$

Moreover, $K$ is the intersection of $y=\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2b}$ and $AC$. So,

$$K=(\frac{a^3+ab^2-a-a^2+b^2+1}{2b^2}, \frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2b}).$$

On the other hand, $H$ is the intersection of $x=a$ and the altitude of the triangle passing through $B$ whose equation is $y=(\frac{1-a}{b})(x+1)$. Hence,

$$H=(a, \frac{1-a^2}{b}), $$

and,

$$I=(a, \frac{1-a^2+b^2}{2b}). $$

Now, if $m$ and $m'$ are respectively the slopes of $BI$ and $IK$, we just need to show $mm'=-1$, while we have:

$$mm'=\frac{\frac{1-a^2+b^2}{2b}}{a+1} \times \frac{\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2b}-\frac{1-a^2+b^2}{2b}}{\frac{a^3+ab^2-a-a^2+b^2+1}{2b^2}-a} \\ =\frac{\frac{1-a^2+b^2}{2b}}{a+1} \times \frac{\frac{a^2-1}{b}}{\frac{a^3-ab^2-a-a^2+b^2+1}{2b^2}} \\ = \frac{(1-a^2+b^2)(a-1)}{a^3-ab^2-a-a^2+b^2+1}=-1.$$

we are done.

Comment: I am confused. Why have you assumed $B=(-1,0), C=(1,0)$ as nothing is mentioned in the question about the dimensions of the triangle?

Comment: @Souparna Hi. When we multiply the sides of the triangle by a number, the angles in the figure do not change. That means we can assume that the length of $BC$ is $2$, or any other number. That's why I chose those points. Anyway, you can choose any other points as $B$ and $C$ on the coordinate system. That choice was a matter of simple computation. I hope it helps ...

Comment: Thank you for your solution Reza, it's very nice. I still looking for a solution in the language of similarity of triangle.

Answer (score 2):

There are an extreme amount of facts in this configuration. Letting $E$ be such that $OKCE$ is an isosceles trapezoid, and $D$ being the reflection of the orthocenter of $BC$, we get many facts. Let $M=\frac{B+K}{2}$. My favorites are i) $OKEB$ is a parallelogram, and ii) $DE=EO=OK=KC$ and $D,O,E,K,C$ lie on a circle.

To actually solve the problem, there are many approaches. Here's one that I thought was not too hard to find:

Draw the circle centered at $M$ passing through $B,K$, and call it $\Omega$. Then $D\in \Omega$. This isn't hard to prove; show that $OM$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BD$, and hence $MB=MD$. One way to show that $OM$ is the perpendicular bisector is with $E$. I claim $OKEB$ is a parallelogram, so that $M$ is also the midpoint of $OE$. This is true because $OK||EB$ and $\angle OKB=\angle OCB=\angle OBC$. Since $OB=OD$ is the radius $R$ of $(ABC)$, it's enough to show $OE$ is said bisector. Look at angles. It's enough to show $D,O,E,K$ are concyclic.

You can finish by showing $I\in \Omega$ via angles (which solves the problem by Thales), or by directly showing $\angle BIK=\pi/2$ via lengths -- $IB^2+IK^2=DB^2+DK^2$. To compute $IB$, note that it's a median in $\triangle BHA$. To compute $DB$, note $DB=BH$. To compute $IK$, look at $\triangle IAK$ and observe $KO=KC=EB$. Finally, to compute $DK$, note $DEKC$ is a cyclic isosceles trapezoid, so $KD=EC$.

The details are not difficult to fill in. The below diagram is enlightening:
[image: diagram]